# object reference not set to an instance in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () 
{
    if (walking)
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + Camera.main.transform.forward * .5f * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ViewportPointToRay(new Vector3(.5F, .5F, 0));     //this is line 23
    RaycastHit hit;
```

seems logical to me, however I am getting an

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Comment: Does your camera have "MainCamera" tag?

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint? If so, do Camera and main have a value or are they null?

Comment: Agreed to Ognjen, when you're trying to access `Camera.main` there must be a camera with `MainCamera` tag in running Scene.